# Excel VBA formula as text issue

Tags: vba, excel

In my Excel 2016 VBA I have this code:

```
Range("M2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(E2=""Sgl"",K2,L2),"")"
```

when it gets placed in the cell it is the formula not the result.  To manually fix this I have to change from Text to General and also the actual code needs changing:

Cell M2 says: `=IFERROR(IF(E2="Sgl",K2,L2),")`
It should say: `=IFERROR(IF(E2="Sgl",K2,L2),"")`
with the extra " at the end before the closing parenthesis

This was recorded (I removed the RC to the absolute cell reference initially when it wouldn't work), so I'm not sure what caused this or how to resolve it.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: That can't have been recorded. Any formula used while the macro recorder is running will use the R1C1 syntax, not A1. The recorded formula looks like this  `"=IFERROR(IF(R[1]C[3]=""Sgl"",R[1]C[9],R[1]C[10]),"""")"`. I think someone edited it to change the R1C1 notation to A1 and took out the "extra" quotes in the process.

Comment: I changed it to take out the RC as I thought that might fix it initially, but it didn't

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to add the extra quote at the end.  Because the quote denotes a string, you need to make two of them to yield one -- which means you need four to yield two.

```
Range("M2").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(E2=""Sgl"",K2,L2),"""")"
```

Other notes of interest:

- You don't need to `Range().Select` and then work against `ActiveCell`.  Just invoke the methods/properties directly on the Range Object
- I think in your case `Formula` will work.  `R1C1` is handy when the formulas are relative, but in this case, you are referencing actual cells.  There is nothing wrong with what you did, but FYI

Answer (score 1):

To generate the two double quotes ("") in IFERROR, you need to put 4 double quotes ("""") in the vba string literal.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing the IFERROR part as if there was no value in the proceeding columns it simply left it blank anyway rather than showing an error message:

```
Columns("M:P").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
Range("M2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-8]=""SGL"",RC[-2],RC[-1])"
Range("M2").Select
```